# Good statistical tests for mutual exclusivity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

Let's say I really want the ability to distinguish two datasets.

The first set $A$ has data has $N$ "mutually exclusive" data points defined as: $(x,y,z) = (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1),\dots$

The second set $B$ just has $N$ copies of the average of the first dataset: $(x,y,z) = (0.33,0.33,0.33), (0.33,0.33,0.33) \dots$

Obviously I can't distinguish these two datasets by taking the average. I can, however, distinguish these two datasets by the variance. In fact, the higher powers I sum, the better discrimination I seem to get:

$$ \frac{\sum A_i^{n+1}}{\sum B_i^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{0.33^{n+1} } > \frac{1}{0.33^n}$$

Is there a standard way of thinking about problems like this? I am a little rusty on my data analysis.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us some context where this arises? As presente using the variance seems to solve the problem, why not go with that?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen in cancer, driver mutations that use the same mechanism will be mutually exclusive in tumor sequencing. You will either have one or the other https://academic.oup.com/bib/article/20/1/254/4100222

Comment: Maybe you can expand on that in the Q itself?

Comment: It's unclear what class of problems you might have in mind: each individual reading this question might have a different interpretation of what "problems like this" means.  If you're still interested in an answer, then please frame your question more specifically.

Comment: I guess looking back years ago I was interested in testing whether there were variables in a dataset that were mutually exclusive i.e. they anticorrelate. I was wondering if there were any specific statistical tests of this. I think just looking for negatives in the correlation matrix may solve this. @whuber